# Generating, segregating, merging, and sorting random numbers

Tags: java, sorting, performance

I've been working on this elevator program for quite some time now and finally finished it and made it work and I'm pretty proud of myself, but I'd like to see ways how to optimize my code so I can learn for the future. By optimizing I mean, making the code look better, maybe by using less lines of codes.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args) {

        Random r = new Random();
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            nums.add( r.nextInt( 100000) * ((i % 4 == 0) ? 1 : -1));
        }

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // part 1

        int lastPositivePos = getLastPositivePosition( nums);
        System.out.println( "lastPositivePos " + lastPositivePos + " has value " + nums.get( lastPositivePos));

        Set<Integer> positiveNumbers = removeNegativeNumbers( nums);
        Set<Integer> negativeNumbers = removePositiveNumbers( nums);

        System.out.println( positiveNumbers.size() + " + " + negativeNumbers.size() + " should be 5000");

        // part 2

        List<Integer> positiveList = repeatElements( positiveNumbers, 5);
        List<Integer> negativeList = repeatElements( negativeNumbers, 5);
        Collection<Integer> merged = mergeAndSort( negativeList, positiveList);
        System.out.println( merged.size() + " sorted elements");

        // part 3
Map<Integer, Integer> nums2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            nums2.put( r.nextInt( 100), r.nextInt( 100));
        }
        mergeEvenNumbers( nums2);

        long d = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
        System.out.println( "test takes " + d);
    }

    private static List<Integer> repeatElements( Collection<Integer> nums, int repeat) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            for ( int num : nums) {
                result.add( num);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * if two keys are even, add the keys together and the values together, until only one even key remains.
     * 
     * @param nums2
     */
    private static void mergeEvenNumbers( Map<Integer, Integer> nums2) {

        int currentSize = 0;
        while ( currentSize != nums2.size()) {
            currentSize = nums2.size();
            int evenKey = -1;

            for ( int key : nums2.keySet()) {
                if ( key % 2 == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ( evenKey < 0) {
                    evenKey = key;
                } else {
                    // merge keys and values
                    int val1 = nums2.remove( evenKey);
                    int val2 = nums2.remove( key);
                    nums2.put( key + evenKey, val1 + val2);
                    evenKey = -1;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private static Collection<Integer> mergeAndSort( List<Integer> nums1, List<Integer> nums2) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        result.addAll( nums1);
        result.addAll( nums2);
        Collections.sort( result);
        return result;
    }

    private static Set<Integer> removePositiveNumbers( List<Integer> list) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if ( list.get( i) > 0) {
                list.remove( i);
            }
        }
        return new HashSet<Integer>( list);
    }

    private static Set<Integer> removeNegativeNumbers( List<Integer> list) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if ( list.get( i) < 0) {
                list.remove( i);
            }
        }
        return new HashSet<Integer>( list);
    }

    private static int getLastPositivePosition( List<Integer> nums) {
        int result = -1;
        for ( int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if ( nums.get( i) > 0) {
                result = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: One word of advice: walls of code in a main method decrease the usefulness of your code.  Better to encapsulate it into an object with a method you could call in other contexts (e.g. a web app with a browser UI).  Think harder about names: "Test" tells me absolutely nothing about this class or how I might use it.

Comment: Please don't confuse "look better" with "less lines of code"

Answer (score 3):

Good job! Whatever is written below, you wrote some good code (with a few issues). You're on the correct path, so keep trying, keep learning, keep writing code! The mentioned issues:

1. The general consensus is that there's no space after the opening parenthesis in a method call or declaration. Therefore, `public static void main( String[] args)` shoud be `public static void main(String[] args)`.
2. Any time you catch yourself writing a title of a code block into a comment, you should make a method (or a test class instance) instead. For example, instead of `// part 1` you should have it as an appropriately named method.
3. `List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();` can be written as `List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();` since Java 7. It's called [Diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7).
4. Since Java 7, there's a new [`ThreadLocalRandom` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). It gives you the same results as `Random`, but is only safe for single-threaded usage, and the implementation therefore lacks some synchronization details and is faster. Of course, this only shows up when generating lots of numbers, but it's better to use the single-threaded classes when not dealing with multiple threads in general.
5. There's no need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` when you're not dealing with multiple threads. Simply use a `HashMap`. The reason you probably went for the concurrent map was that you needed to remove from the map while iterating over it, and you were getting `ConcurrentModificationExeptions`. You can do it with a normal `HashMap` easily, too, [just use iterators and their `remove()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231022/is-there-any-way-to-cast-arraylist-to-copyonwritearraylist/17231122#17231122).
6. Your `mergeEvenNumbers()` works (partly due to the hack above), but does too much work for no reason. What it does:

   1. Goes over all entries
   2. Finds two even keys
   3. Removes the previous even entry and the current even entry
   4. Puts in a new entry which is the sum
   5. (plus some looping around that to make sure you did it enough times and nothing changes anymore)

   The problem is that you don't need to do most of that. What you should do:

   1. Loop over the map, remove all even keys while summing their keys and values into twe local temporary variables.
   2. Put the sums into the map.

   The final code:

   ```
   private static void mergeEvenNumbers(Map<Integer, Integer> nums) {
       int keySum = 0;
       int valueSum = 0;
       for (Iterator<Integer> iter = nums.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
           int key = iter.next();
           if (key % 2 == 1) {
               continue;
           }
           keySum += key;
           valueSum += nums.get(key);
           iter.remove();
       }
       nums.put(keySum, valueSum);
   }
   ```

   Much shorter, does the same thing.
7. Your `getLastPositivePosition()` ... why does it go over the whole list? It's generally easier to start at the end of the list and go backwards - once you find a positive number, you're done. The code is similarly long, but does a lot less work!

   ```
   private static int getLastPositivePosition(List<Integer> nums) {
       for (int i = nums.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if (nums.get(i) > 0) {
               return i;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }
   ```
8. Your `repeatElements()`: instead of

   ```
   for (int num : nums) {
       result.add(num);
   }
   ```

   you could have `result.addAll(nums)`
9. Your `removePositiveNumbers()` and `removeNegativeNumbers()` are very flawed!

   They iterate based on an index, and remove from the lists as they do (Oh, by the way, that's a very costly thing to do when dealing with `ArrayLists`. Either iterate backwards, use a `Set`, or at last a `LinkedList`. This makes a *huge* difference regarding speed.). Therefore, they will skip elements immediately after a remove. Consider this list:

   ```
   [-1, -2, 3]
   ```

   Your method would find the -1, remove it, and suddenly you'd end up with a list like this:

   ```
   [-2, 3]
   ```

   But the method would then look up the element on index 1 which is the `3`. It would never remove the `-2`. The fix is to use the iterator-based removal.
10. `removePositiveNumbers()` again: Both methods return a `Set` which removes duplicates. Is that what you want? If yes, it's a very nasty thing to do - your method has a return value, but also changes its parameter. In general, you should do either one of these - if you change your parameters, return `void`. If you want to return an entirely new collection, don't change your parameter. Changes like these are called [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) and should be avoided.

    Your method's names only suggest they remove positive (negative) elements, but they also do one additional thing. Either change the name (and/or the documentation) of the methods, or move the deduplication out of the methods, into its own dedicated method `removeDuplicates()`.
11. Because of the above, this code:

    ```
    Set<Integer> positiveNumbers = removeNegativeNumbers(nums);
    Set<Integer> negativeNumbers = removePositiveNumbers(nums);
    ```

    is flawed. The second line should return a list of the negative numbers from the original `nums`, but there are no negative numbers anymore, we removed them by calling `removeNegativeNumbers(nums)` on the previous line!

The final code with all of the above and something extra, too:

```
public class Test {
    private static final Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> nums = generateRandomNumberList();

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // part 1
        int lastPositivePos = getLastPositivePosition(nums);
        System.out.println("lastPositivePos " + lastPositivePos + " has value " + nums.get(lastPositivePos));

        List<Integer> positiveNumbers = removeNegativeNumbers(nums);
        List<Integer> negativeNumbers = removePositiveNumbers(nums);

        System.out.println(positiveNumbers.size() + " + " + negativeNumbers.size() + " should be ~100000");

        // part 2
        List<Integer> positiveList = repeatElements(positiveNumbers, 5);
        List<Integer> negativeList = repeatElements(negativeNumbers, 5);
        List<Integer> mergedList = mergeAndSort(negativeList, positiveList);
        System.out.println(mergedList.size() + " sorted elements");

        // part 3
        Map<Integer, Integer> nums2 = generateRandomNumberMap();
        mergeEvenNumbers(nums2);

        System.out.println("test takes " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms");
    }

    private static List<Integer> generateRandomNumberList() {
//      a longer Java 8 alternative
//      the point to ever use this would be to leave it as an IntStream and operate on that if possible (which it isn't here)
//      int i = 0;
//      random.ints(0, 100000)
//              .map(num -> num * ((i++ % 4 == 0) ? 1 : -1))
//              .limit(100000)
//              .boxed()
//              .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            nums.add(random.nextInt(100000) * ((i % 4 == 0) ? 1 : -1));
        }
        return nums;
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> generateRandomNumberMap() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> nums = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            nums.put(random.nextInt(100), random.nextInt(100));
        }
        return nums;
    }

    private static int getLastPositivePosition(List<Integer> nums) {
        for (int i = nums.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nums.get(i) > 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static List<Integer> removeNegativeNumbers(List<Integer> list) {
//      a Java 8 alternative
//      return list.stream()
//              .filter(num -> num > 0)
//              .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>(list);
        for (Iterator<Integer> iter = result.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            if (iter.next() < 0) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> removePositiveNumbers(List<Integer> list) {
//      a Java 8 alternative
//      return list.stream()
//              .filter(num -> num < 0)
//              .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>(list);
        for (Iterator<Integer> iter = result.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            if (iter.next() > 0) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> repeatElements(List<Integer> nums, int repeat) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(repeat * nums.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            result.addAll(nums);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> mergeAndSort(List<Integer> nums1, List<Integer> nums2) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(nums1.size() + nums2.size());
        result.addAll(nums1);
        result.addAll(nums2);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    /** Merges all even keys to a single entry, sum them and their values. */
    private static void mergeEvenNumbers(Map<Integer, Integer> nums) {
        int keySum = 0;
        int valueSum = 0;
        for (Iterator<Integer> iter = nums.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            int key = iter.next();
            if (isOdd(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            keySum += key;
            valueSum += nums.get(key);
            iter.remove();
        }
        nums.put(keySum, valueSum);
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int key) {
//      return ((key & 1) == 1);    // a faster alternative
        return ((key % 2) == 1);
    }
}
```